# How to set query timeout using Atom Editor & Data-Atom?

Tags: sql-server, atom-editor

I'm start using [Atom](https://atom.io/) with the package [Data-Atom](https://atom.io/packages/data-atom) for SQL Server connection.

But I keep getting this error when I execute a query:

> Results:
>      "Error (ETIMEOUT) - Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms"

But on Visual Studio the same query executes without errors, so the server is ok I presume.

There is a way to resolve this?

Comment: requestTimeout attribute on the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: The connection options weren't being passed through to `node-mssql` but after [this PR](https://github.com/lukemurray/data-atom/pull/113) is merged they will be.

In my attempt to set the timeout to one hour I added the below to `data-atom-connections.cson`.

```
{
    name: "sqlserver01"
    protocol: "sqlserver"
    user: "dzamo"
    password: "norton"
    server: "sqlserver01.localdomain"
    database: "AdventureWorks"

    options: "requestTimeout=36000000"
}
```

And nothing happened.  I had to go and hardcode it in `~/.atom/packages/data-atom/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js` to get a long-running query to work.  I'll investigate this a bit more and open a bug on github.